Unity Catalog Databricks got error "Filesystem not supported by this committer"
I want to write a file to S3 from Databricks
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.PathCommitException: `s3a://shared/export/databricks.txt': Filesystem not supported by this committer
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.AbstractS3ACommitterFactory.createOutputCommitter(AbstractS3ACommitterFactory.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(FileOutputFormat.java:338)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupCommitter(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:195)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1077)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
On Databricks Cluster (Unity Catalog Databricks) -> Advanced Options -> Spark Conf -> I added
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
However, when I checked logs, I found that it used other filesystem instead of org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem while hadoop desires S3AFileSystem
22.04.2024 08:21:23 [INFO]             fs.s3a.impl=com.databricks.sql.acl.fs.CredentialScopeFileSystem 22.04.2024 08:21:23 [INFO]              fs.s3a.impl.disable.cache=true 22.04.2024 08:21:23 [INFO]              fs.s3a.impl.disable.cache.old=true 22.04.2024 08:21:23 [INFO]              fs.s3a.impl.old=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem -> become old one "fs.s3a.impl.old"
Do you guys know what the reason is? Thank you!

It's missing the full path, the full path kind of `s3a://shared/export/databricks.txt'

databricks have their own filesystem; s3a committers require S3AFileSystem only.
